# How to accept 0 as a value in a list? and When I enter the numbers after a space I get an error

Tags: python

Everytime I enter a value such as 002
the length comes out as 1 however it should come out as 3
My code is:

```
list1  = int(input("Enter a number"))
list1 = [int(x) for x in str(list1)]
print (len(list1))
```

If I type in a number after a space I get an error saying:

```
File "C:\\practice11.py", line 2, in <module>
  list1 = [int(x) for x in text]
File "C:\\practice11.py", line 2, in <listcomp>
  list1 = [int(x) for x in text]
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Comment: Your desired output is `list1 = ['0', '0', '2']`?

Comment: What do you think `int("002")` is equal to?

Comment: is it necessary to have the values be ints? Can they be string instead

Comment: The number has to be an integer but I resolved

Comment: I have another problem now:
When I press enter then type in my number python gives me an error how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

Don't convert your input to a int. If you convert your the string `002` to a int, the leading zeros are gone, because `002` is the same number as `2`. Converting to string again leads to `2`, which only has a length of 1.

```
text  = input("Enter a number")
list1 = [int(x) for x in text]
print(len(list1))
```

Comment: You should probably mention why it affects the length and how `int("002")` actually works.

Answer (score 0):

You're casting the input to an integer with `int`, so you're removing trailing zeroes. Integers don't preserve their trailing zeroes, so when converted it becomes a single digit:

```
int("002")
# 2
```

You should remove the first int call, save it as a string until you split it up in the list comprehension:

```
list1  = input("Enter a number")
list1 = [int(x) for x in str(list1)]
print (len(list1))
# 3
```

Comment: @Th1L4K Integers don't have trailing zeroes. So `002` just becomes `2`, which is then turned into the string `"2"`.

Comment: When I press enter then type in my number python gives me an error how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Because you cast the user input `"002"` to an int with value `2`. Then, in your list comprehension you cast it back to a string `"2"`, over which you iterate (once).

The result of your list comprehension is thus `["2"]`, a list of length 1.

So instead of casting back and forth you could:

```
list1 = [int(x) for x in input("Enter a number")]
```

Which will give you `list1 = [0, 0, 2]`, a list of integers with a total length of 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
s = "002"
i = int(s)
print(i)
```

outputs

```
2
```

because leading 0 are dropped during the casting to int. As a matter of fact,

```
i = 002
```

is illegal and yields

```
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

So you can't go `string > int > string` to count the characters, why not doing this instead:

```
s = input("Enter a number")
print (len(s))
```